RPC node syncing from scratch after upgrading node version to 1.14.1 from 1.0.0
I upgraded my rpc node from 1.0.0 node verison to 1.14.1 node version (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/releases/tag/polkadot-v1.14.1), and my node started to sync from scratch. Any reason for it or how can we sync it faster? Is there official snapshot available for pruned node. I am running testnet node on  Westend Test Network with rocksdb databse
